# Execute Multiple Select Statement in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to confirm that can we execute multiple select statement in one shot and get multiple resultsets. Please give me some idea for doing this.

I have to execute two select query in one statement:-

```
String sql="select * form test;  
select * from test where empid=1;"
```

I am expecting to run like this :-

```
statement.execute(sql);
```

thanks

Comment: Please give a more accurate example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/302950/JDBC/databases/Batching-Select-Statements-JDBC. This might help.

Comment: see here http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp

Comment: u need to use Batch Execution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *believe* that standard JDBC supports this. Certainly the [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) interface is oriented towards "multiple rows, one row at a time" - but not "multiple sets of results".

That doesn't mean it's not feasible with your specific database, however - it's possible that there's a driver for your database which extends JDBC to allow it. If you specify which database and driver you're using, we could verify that more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure with those set of select statements and use [Statement.getMoreResults()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) to check whether you have more ResultSets and use 
[Statement.getResultSet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29) to get the next ResultSet

An example is given [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvjdmlt.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion JDBC does not allow executing multiple statements in one go. The language used in the JDBC specification and API doc indicates that the expectation is that one `Statement` execution is one statement, not multiple statements (eg it uses *'a SQL statement'*, which when reading the SQL spec means a single SELECT, INSERT, etc). However it never explicitly states it is not allowed.

Some drivers do support execution of multiple statements in one execution, but this usually has to be explicitly enabled using a connection property. Also some databases support executing a block of stored procedure code without explicitly defining a stored procedure (in that case the block is considered to be the statement).